# What are the style guidelines for tabs in Android 3.0?

Tags: android, styles, icons, android-tabs, design-guidelines

The next websites give explanation and guidelines of how to style the tabs and icons on android up to Android 3.0 (honeycomb) excluding this version:

- http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-tab.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html
- http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

but I can't find the guidelines to Android 3.0 and above. Where are they?

Also, are there any other missing guidelines that need to be read?

The tabs I want to use are meant for an activity with both tabs and viewPager (like the tabs pager example of the compatibility package).

Answer (score 2):

Android Design, where you can found the guidelines, was launched in January 2012. Before this date, Google didn't say which guidelines we must follow. This is the cause you can't find guidelines before android 3.0.

This is enough: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

EDIT: And this: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

Comment: this is just the main page . i want info about guidelines of tabs .

Comment: I added a new link. I hope that this is what are you looking for.

Comment: i wrote tabs . not tablets . tabs . like this one : http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/ or this one: http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/viewpager.html

Answer (score 0):

found this one:

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=example&theme=light

not sure though if it's for tabs on android 3.0 and above . since it's for the action bar , it might be the correct one .